# How to list Context/Apartments for COM Object?

Tags: c++, .net, debugging, com

I am using the vs2008 debbuger for a C++ project that uses COM objects of a .NET assembly.

I am getting a `'DisconnectedContext'` message from the managed debugging assistant, but I can't figure out which of the pointers is holding a reference to a bad COM object.

Is it possible to keep track of the apartment/context in a thread with Visual Studio? Or can I at least get a hold on the Runtime Callable Wrapper created for each of my COM object?